# How can I not include a line in the action page if the corresponding form field was left empty?

Tags: php, forms

Suppose I have the following form, where the input field `Phone` is optional.

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   Phone (optional): <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to display the submitted data in the `action` page. So here it is the `welcome.php` page:

```
<html>
   <body>
      Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
      Your phone number is: <?php echo $_POST["phone"]; ?>
      Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

My question is how can I exclude the `Your phone number is: <?php echo $_POST["phone"]; ?>` section if the user doesn't input any value for the Phone in the form? Simply saying, if user leaves a field empty, the corresponding sentence will not be generated in the action page.

What would be the best possible way to achieve that?

I'm just trying to learn the different approaches of form handling. I'll appreciate any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if($_POST["phone"] == '') ?

Comment: Please, never output user submitted content directly without checking it, like you did here: `echo $_POST["email"];`.

Comment: *"if user leaves a field empty"* - You basically answered your own question with the "empty" keyword.

Comment: Ha ha ... yes, it turned out that I hovered over the answer button didn't know to click it..  :)  @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a condition that checks if the variable isn't empty.
If so, print the required line.

```
<?php if(!empty($_POST['phone'])) {   
      echo 'Your phone number is: '. $_POST["phone"] . '<br />';
}
?>
```

**Note:** Consider validating/escaping the input data prior to printing them.

Update - In case of multiple fields:

```
$fields = array(
'phone' => 'This is my phone number',
'address' => 'I live at',
'zipcode' => 'And my zip code is:'
);

foreach($fields as $fieldname => $label){
  $value = $_POST[$fieldname]; //consider escaping/validating the value...
  if(!empty($value)){
     echo $label . ' ' . $value . '<Br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: you can easily call `!empty($_POST['phone'])`

Comment: Thanks for your response. But suppose I have lots of fields that are optional. Should I check each of them weather there has been any input or not with this code separately for each of them? I mean woudn't that be a long sets of codes?

Comment: @insertusernamehere It was there at the beginning...argg

Comment: You should use a generic condition in a loop.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. This is what I have been looking for. I really appreciate your effort. It was a good lesion.  :)  @OfirBaruch

Comment: you're welcome. If my answer has helped you please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
<html>
   <body>
      Welcome <?= $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
       <?= (!empty($_POST["phone"])) ? 'Your phone number is: ' . $_POST["phone"] : ''; ?>
      Your email address is: <?= $_POST["email"]; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

This uses a `?:` *ternary operator* to determine if the `$_POST["phone"]` is empty or not. Also use `<?=` shorthand for `<?php echo` when `echo`ing inside html tags.

## Warning

Also, beware of **XSS** use `htmlentities()` to escape the output like `htmlentities($_POST["phone"])` also, use more specific validation for filtering `phone` and `email` strings.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried to simply the question that's why I omitted the validation. But seems like it's really a dangerous practice to leave it even in questions.  :)

Comment: @Ashonko Well, SO users love to give `SQL Injection` and `XSS` warnings. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Check post fields are having values or not like below:

```
<html>
   <body>
    <?php if(!empty($_POST['name'])) echo 'Welcome '. $_POST['name'] ?><br>
    <?php if(!empty($_POST["phone"])) echo 'Your phone number is: '. $_POST["phone"]; ?>
    <?php if(!empty($_POST["email"])) echo 'Your email address is: '. $_POST["email"]; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```